# Error en @Schedule en wildfly 11

Tags: java, wildfly

Estoy realizando una tarea automática en java mi finalidad es que se ejecute los primeros de cada mes, pero para pruebas estoy utilizando @Schedule para que me muestre un mensaje cada 1 minuto y esta es la respuesta de la consola:

> WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.timer] (EJB default - 3) WFLYEJB0161: Failed
>   to reinstate timer 'proyect-name-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.TimerSessionBean'
>   (id=deleted-timer) from its persistent state
>
> ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.timer] (EJB default - 4) WFLYEJB0029: Could
>   not restore timer from
>   C:\Users\nameuser\Desktop\carpeta\wildfly\wildfly\standalone\data\timer-service-data\proyect-name-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.TimerSessionBean\1d065458-0da2-4a3b-9cdb-a22042880c29.xml:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog  at
>   [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]

El código que estoy tratando para realizar esto es:

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;  
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton  
public class TimerSessionBean {

    @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "*/1", hour = "*")
    public void atSchedule() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("DeclarativeScheduler:: In atSchedule()"+new Date());
    }
}
```

Comment: Prueba en una version limpia de wildfly, posiblemente un archivo se haya corrompido, acabo de probar en mi local y funciono correctamente.